# ASP.Net Checkbox conditional Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a webform with a checkbox in it.  I need to do two things differently based on an environment setting.

1. Add a class
2. Add the Text attribute so a label gets created

   ```
                           <% if setting == true) { %>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="optionCheckbox" class="option-checkbox radio-checkbox" runat="server" Text="Label Text"/>
                           <% } else { %>
                           <asp:CheckBox ID="optionCheckbox" class="option-checkbox" runat="server"/>
                           <% } %>
   ```

The problem with this is the page won't render because the ids are the same, even though only one could ever get rendered.  There is a lot of other processing with javascript and such so I don't want different ids for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by keeping only the "base" checkbox code below and then overriding the PreRender event to add the class and set the Text attribute there.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="optionCheckbox" class="option-checkbox" runat="server"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
                CheckBox optionCheckbox = this.optionCheckbox as CheckBox;
                if (optionCheckbox != null)
                {
                    optionCheckbox.Text = "Label Text";
                    optionCheckbox.Attributes.Add("class", "option-checkbox radio-checkbox");
                }
```

I'd still like to know if there is a way to do this in the markup file though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this syntax , I don't use ASPNet webPage.
You can implement it logically..

Firstly , define class and text variable  and set value for business..

Finaly set `checkbox` `class` and `Text` value by variable

```
var class = "option-checkbox";
var text = "";
if(setting == true)
{
    class = "option-checkbox radio-checkbox";
    text  = "Label Text"; 
}

 <asp:CheckBox ID="optionCheckbox" class="setClassProperty" runat="server" Text="SetTextProperty"/>
```

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing but won't quite work as written.  Thank you though.